# VideoJS subtitle menu not showing

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I have a problem and I searched all over the web but I cant seem to find a solution.

I got this code

```
     <!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Video.JS Example</title>
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.2.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.2.2/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:700px;margin:0px auto;">
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
               controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
               poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
               data-setup='{"controls":true}'>
            <source src="http://x/watch/Inside.Out.HD1080.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<track src="http://x/watch/subtitles/en/Inside.Out.HD1080.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"/>
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
```

But when I run it everything works but the subtitle selection doesnt display
Here look:
[image]

Comment: have tried `<track kind="subtitles" src="" srclang="en" 
label="English" default>`

Comment: Yes of course, thats what I tried first

Comment: Care to share the VTT file?

Comment: I copied your code and linked to a local video and vtt file. What I get is the same: the videojs player, and no captions/subtitles. BUT I also get a subtitles select button (bottom right, just before the fullscreen button) which indicates that subtitles are "off" and allows me to activate "English". The subtitles then appear. Not the answer, but you should check out why that select button has disappeared from your player and maybe google how to set subtitles "on" by default.

Comment: @Broonix Sure thing mate, how do you want me to send it to you

Comment: I know how to do that @plugincontainer but I want multiple subs

Comment: Just make a http://pastebin.com/ of the files contents.

Comment: If I change the link to a non-existent vtt file, the select-subtitle does not appear. If I link to an empty vtt file it does. So maybe you got the vtt file name wrong in your html?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your javascript, after loading videojs.

```
            function loadCaptionsifAny() {
                var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
                track = document.createElement("track");
                track.kind = "captions";
                track.label = "English";
                track.srclang = "en";
                track.src = "captions/captions.vtt";
                video.appendChild(track);
                video.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
            }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue!